# python reverse proxy on web server, socket recv is too slow

Tags: python, web-services, sockets, webserver, reverse-proxy

I am trying to write a reverse proxy for out webserver which is running on apache
for this I have shifted the webserver of the port 8008, and now my plan is to run reverse proxy on port 80. for this I have written some Python code.

the reverse proxy code opens a socket on port 80 and wait for a connection, as soon as it receives a connection request it forks a thread and pass the connection socket to this thread.
below is my code for this

```
class rp_server:
 def __init__(self, mod):
    self.host = Constants.HOST_NAME
    self.port = Constants.RP_PORT
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    settings.mod = mod
    if settings.mod == "reset":
        print("reseting the cache\n")
        exit()
    else:
        self.start_rp_server()

def start_rp_server(self):
    self.socket.listen(5)
    while True:
        print("waiting for a connection")
        (clientsocket, (ip, port)) = self.socket.accept()
        print("connected to : " +ip + ":" + str(port))
        t = ClientThread.ClientThread(ip, port, clientsocket)
        t.start()

start = rp_server(mod)
```

Now the run method of `ClientThread` receives the msg from `clientsocket`, create a new socket on port 8008 (where my web server is running), send the msg to server which it received from `clientsocket`, receive back the response, forward the response back to `clientsocket`, close the `clientsocket`
below is code of this part

```
def run(self):
  data = self.clientsocket.recv(Constants.SKT_BUF_SIZE)
 start = time.time()
    print("creating a socket with web server\n")
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    server_address = (Constants.HOST_NAME, Constants.WEB_HOST_PORT)
    sock.connect(server_address)
    sock.send(data)
    try:
        while True:
            print("receiving from web server\n")
            response = sock.recv(Constants.SKT_BUF_SIZE)
            if not response:
                print("end of response\n")
                break

            self.clientsocket.send(response)
    finally:
        sock.close()
        sys.exit()
```

Now the issue is when I am trying to open the page localhost:80 on my browser it is taking too much time to load, when I put some logs I saw that

```
       response = sock.recv(Constants.SKT_BUF_SIZE)
```

part of the code taking too much time eventhough everything is running on my local machine.

Is there any better way to achieve this in python?
What are the faster alternative to achieve this?, Idealy the reverse proxy part should be seemless, it should work with the same speed as the normal website without reverse proxy will work.

Comment: TL; DR; but I think `self.socket.listen(5)` should be outside the `while loop`.